How to insert List and Link elements into CKEditor5 from a custom plugin
I'm trying to create a ckeditor5 plugin that inserts a list of links into the editor when a toolbar button is pressed.
The code I have only inserts the links as text, and no list when the button is pressed.
For the context :

It is in typescript,
I compile in js and import my plugin in a Strapi (headless CMS) plugin that integrates CkEditor5 (ckeditor5 plugin).
I think the list plugin (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list) is required but my CKEditor5 from strapi probably have it bundled since the list buttons are available in the toolbar.
ckeditor5 toolbar list buttons screenshot

  public async init(): Promise<void> {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const model = editor.model;
    const links = ["https://www.google.fr", "https://www.google.com"];

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add("damButton", (locale) => {
      const button = new ButtonView(locale);
      const t = editor.t;
      button.set({
        label: t("INSERT LIST"),
        withText: true,
        tooltip: true,
        isToggleable: true
      });
      button.on("execute", () => {
        try {
          model.change((writer) => {
            // Create the list element
            const listElement = writer.createElement("ul", {
              listType: 'bulleted',
              indent: 0,
            });
            // Iterate over the links and create list items with links
            links.forEach((link) => {
              const listItem = writer.createElement("li", {
                 listType: 'bulleted',
                 indent: 1,
              });
              const linkElement = writer.createElement("a", { href: link });
              writer.insertText(link, linkElement);
              writer.append(linkElement, listItem);
              writer.append(listItem, listElement);
            });
            // Insert the list element into the editor's model
            editor.model.insertContent(listElement, editor.model.document.selection.getLastPosition());
          });
          editor.editing.view.focus();
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Error", e);
        }
      });
      return button;
    });

I checked createElement documentation but did not understand how to properly use it:
createElement
